# Problem with OS Ubuntu 17.10 hangs when working with video

Tags: 17.10, vlc, video-player

Has anyone encountered such a problem?
On my PC is installed OS Ubuntu 17.10 Very often, after watching the video, when I click on the close button of the video player, no matter what default Gnome or VLC, the system hangs for a while.
Tried to change the players, the same.
The OS was updated through the "System Update" for the first time and this described trouble was. I thought that maybe the problem arose during the system update and decided to reinstall the system from scratch with USB. What do you think, the same thing, again everything flies out. But the truth is rarer, somewhere through time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue here. It runs but then eventually hangs and doesn't respond. If I pause it then I can't restart it.
Very weird because VLC has never given me any issues and has been my favorite media player for a decade.

One thing I've read is to disable the "embedded" part so the window and controls are 2 different windows. Trying it now. Tools, Prefs, Show Settings All, search for embed, Video, "Embedded video", deselect it.

So far one day into testing, normal use plus some 4 hour videos and no hangs so the problem appears to be fixed.